# GA4 event for form input

Tags: events, google-analytics, triggers, analytics, google-tag-manager

I want to create event to track form input in my website form. For example someone types in name section, phone sectio or email I want to see that as event in my GA4 account. But I couldn't manage to create triger and event from tag manager. Any tips guys?

I created additional variables threw tag manager. But couldn't create trigger.

Answer (score 0):

GTM's best practices advice not to do so-called DOM scraping. The proper solution here would be you asking your front-end developers to push dataLayer events for which you would be listening from GTM. This way, when things change on the front-end, the developers can effortlessly move the tracking to a new form, or a new field.

In some cases, inferior tracking methods must be used, however. In this case, you would want to deploy a custom HTML, which would be a `<script>` tag in your DOM deploying event listeners on form field interactions. The callbacks of the listeners would deploy dataLayer events with payloads containing whatever else you need to know about the interactions.

After you deploy the listeners and confirm that the callbacks work as you want, you make custom event triggers, indicating your event names from the dataLayer pushes. You can make dataLayer Variables to declare used datapoints in the DL events and use the new variables in your tags.